# Meteor errors internationalization

Tags: internationalization, coffeescript, meteor

I'm trying to implement internationalization through [just-i18n](https://github.com/subhog/meteor-just-i18n) and it works fine so far.

Problem is I'm also using accounts-password and especially [`Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, [callback])`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithpassword).

On login error, the callback has an error object that basically looks like this :

```
{
    details: undefined,
    error: 403,
    errorType: "Meteor.Error",
    message: "User not found [403]",
    reason: "User not found"
}
```

I thought the error code was unique and went with a i18n configuration file like this :

```
i18n.map 'fr_FR',
  login:
    signin: 'S\'authentifier'
  errors:
    403: 'L\'utilisateur n\'existe pas'
```

So I could call it this way :

```
Session.set "error", i18n("errors." + err.error)
```

But actually, no matter what's the error, user not found or incorrect password, the error code is not unique :

```
{
    details: undefined,
    error: 403,
    errorType: "Meteor.Error",
    message: "Incorrect password [403]",
    reason: "Incorrect password"
}
```

As i don't consider checking on a string value really consistent, how can i differenciate both ?

How would I go implementing internationalization with meteor **built-in** login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`403` here is not a Meteor number for the particular error, but rather a [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). The same code can be caused by different errors.

Since the only difference between the error objects you get are `reason` and `message`, you need to use one of them to set up the internationalization code. They shouldn't change too much between Meteor releases, so you should be fine with this solution.

```
i18n.map 'fr_FR',
  login:
    signin: 'S\'authentifier'
  errors:
    403:
      'Incorrect password': 'Le password est incorrectu'
      'User not found': 'L\'utilisateur n\'existe pas'
```

Ah, and don't worry, `login`, `signin`, `errors` and `403` are internally represented as strings as well, so there's nothing inconsistent in such solution.

Comment: I find it quite weird to use plain string sentences as keys but it works as expected and your argument about consistency seems justified enough.