# Internationalization of error codes with tap-i18n

Tags: meteor, internationalization

I'm currently developping a multi languages application using the [tap-i18n](https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n/) package. I wonder how I can translate errors. 
I can grab the code and then display a custom message that I would have written to the translation file before. 
But I saw on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191787/meteor-errors-internationalization) there is a better way of doing this with another i18n package.

Does anyone know if there is way of doing something like with tap-i18n ?

**EDIT :** For now I'm doing something like this :

```
Meteor.call('createNewUser', newUser, function (error, ret)
{
    if (!error)
        displayError(TAPi18n.__('success'), TAPi18n.__('new_user_success'), TAPi18n.__('ok'), "btn-success btn-lg", "success-popup");
    else
    {
        switch (error.error)
        {
            case 403:
                displayError(TAPi18n.__('danger'), TAPi18n.__('new_user_already_exist'), TAPi18n.__('ok'), "btn-danger btn-lg", "danger-popup");
                break;
            default:
                displayError(TAPi18n.__('danger'), TAPi18n.__('new_user_error'), TAPi18n.__('ok'), "btn-danger btn-lg", "danger-popup");
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer might be a bit off-topic, but do you mean application errors? If so, you shouldn't really return that to the users, as this could constitute a security flaw, giving them too much information.

From OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Error_Handling

Thus, you might want to handle the errors, and give the users exactly what you want them to know.

Just include the error messages in your translation, and proceed as with normal strings to translate.

I hope this is of some help :).

**EDIT:**
I understand now what you mean. As far as I know, there's no such option, as there is with just-i18n. As a suggestion for unbloating the code a bit, you could use a helper function such as:

```
function t(keyToTranslate){
  return TAPi18n.__(keyToTranslate)
}
```

And in the code:

```
displayError(t('danger'), t('new_user_already_exist'), t('ok'), "btn-danger btn-lg", "danger-popup");
```

A bit naive suggestion, but there's no functionality to map the errors in this package, as far as I know. The way you're handling it seems correct to me.

Comment: Hum... my post might be a bit vague. I try a Account.createUser and get an error for example when the username is already taken. The user have to be warned of this error and I saw on an other post that you can define error code translation with just-i18n.